# Pass custom header renderer for Group in ag-grid

Tags: ag-grid

Need some help in passing custom header renderer for the multi Group column , when we set **row Group : true** for column Definition.

[image: want to customize this header menu and the styling of "Group"]

Answer (score 0):

Could you perhaps supply an example of what you currently have in your gridOptions and colunDefinitions/columns? Worth knowing is that if you are using autoGroupColumnDef inside gridOptions, that will be the defining columnDefinition overriding the one you normally supply into "columns".

I assume you looked into [custom component-header](https://www.ag-grid.com/documentation/javascript/component-header/) for your issue?

Comment: thanks for replying @Pontus Ekengren !! yes i have taken a look at the document link you have shared, but wasn't sure if headerGroupComponent will work for row groups